Updating the webpack-dev-server page when the html file changes
I'm trying to create a gulp build using webpack-dev-server to reflect changes during development. But in the process I encountered the problem of importing html components using the example @@include("path/_header.html").
Example:
<body>
     @@include("./elements/_header.html")
     <main>
         Content
     </main>
     @@include("./elements/_footer.html")
</body>

To solve the problem with importing components, I found the FileIncludeWebpackPlugin plugin
new FileIncludeWebpackPlugin({
               source: "src/components/pages",
           }),

but when using it when running the webpack-dev-server page it does not automatically reload the changes made to the html file
this is how I configure the server
developer server: {
           port: 3000,
           openly: true,
           historyApiFallback: true,
           hot: true
           view files: [
               nodePath.resolve(__dirname, "src", "**/*.html"),
           ],
       },

Why does this happen and how can it be solved?
Tried to use
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin();

html-loader and file-loader
I also tried to find an alternative plugin instead of FileIncludeWebpackPlugin, but I couldn’t find it

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
